# Could we use public address and private key of a crypto wallet to encrypt a file?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

Like could I store the entirely encrypted file in IPFS and blockchain by having a single private key from my wallet to decrypt it, not by using GPG. I just wonder if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but in general, I would recommend against it, because keys are generally one time use. Most wallets do not reuse keys, they generate new keys for each transaction, for privacy.

However, for Bitcoin, you could use something like this [eccrypto](https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto) (Do your own research on the security of this implementation).

**index.js**

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

var privateKey = new Buffer("c337ded6f56c07205fb7b391654d7d463c9e0c726869523ae6024c9bec878878", "hex");

//var publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKey);
var publicKey = new Buffer("04730a151f545f5dcdb1c6d99fb1251f5c70f216f39ba2681bcf10db16bd582e6720bc881d51f25ffbe961df6a0af24a9d39a4db3d86a7f6b3f9bf4eaac0e4006b", "hex");

// Encrypting the message for B.
eccrypto.encrypt(publicKey, Buffer("msg")).then(function(encrypted) {
    console.log('Encrypted message ' + JSON.stringify(encrypted));
  // B decrypting the message.
  eccrypto.decrypt(privateKey, encrypted).then(function(plaintext) {
    console.log("Decrypted message: ", plaintext.toString());
  });
});
```

**Output**

```
$ node index.js
Encrypted message {"iv":{"type":"Buffer","data":[204,13,168,25,80,255,9,233,111,60,165,204,180,126,53,65]},"ephemPublicKey":{"type":"Buffer","data":[4,192,3,65,241,134,65,186,52,52,250,61,208,189,216,167,122,206,156,152,27,173,69,152,37,138,164,5,54,189,227,88,37,243,220,183,22,204,235,37,212,110,207,66,225,244,25,92,69,223,247,175,218,228,134,210,247,190,211,248,239,77,183,21,36]},"ciphertext":{"type":"Buffer","data":[75,104,205,95,93,108,18,50,220,120,164,224,42,214,75,28]},"mac":{"type":"Buffer","data":[63,243,230,143,99,187,246,241,194,10,247,215,188,163,82,98,140,15,186,158,58,207,170,49,230,143,26,17,117,248,195,143]}}
Decrypted message:  msg
```

Comment: "keys are generally one time use" This is true for Bitcoin but not for Ethereum, where key reuse is the norm.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think it's less of a question of what is the norm, and more of a privacy concern with reusing public keys on the blockchain.

Comment: Reusing keys (or not) on Ethereum would not change anything relating to privacy.

Comment: Could you explain? Isn't address generation deterministic? Aren't transactions public?

Comment: Strange. I don't know what we're arguing about now, as it seems we're in agreement.

Comment: not arguing. I'm not as familiar with ethereum, but the privacy concern is that if you reuse the same addresses in multiple transactions, it provides more information to the senders to link your other transactions. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse

Comment: You don't have to expose your key if you generate and use just for encryption, just don't use that address for a transaction